# Soapui PRO does not show reports in Allure

Tags: maven, reporting, soapui, allure

I am trying to generate Soapui-PRO execution reports with Allure. I downloaded Allure-maven plugin 2.2. I updated the POM file as mentioned below. At command prompt I run the command c:\maven\bin\mvn -o test. The test runs fine, build is successful. But the reports are html format. Can you pls check and let me know

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.smartbear.soapuiMavenTutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>SoapUI-Maven-Tutorial</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SoapUI-Maven-Tutorial</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <parent>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-examples-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.6</aspectj.version>
        <allure.version>1.4.14</allure.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--added jdbc below in build element-->
    </dependencies>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
                        <version>10.2.0</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                        <!--systemPath>C:\maven\ojdbc6.jar</systemPath-->
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <groupId>com.smartbear</groupId>
                <artifactId>ready-api-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectFile>C:\Gee-SoapUI-Projects-Backup\25Aug2015-POSBkup\May04-2015-Point of Sale.xml</projectFile>
                            <outputFolder>C:\25-Aug-1suiteResults</outputFolder>
                            <reportFormat>xUNIT</reportFormat>
                            <reportName>TestCase Report</reportName>
                            <!--reportName>TestSuite Report</reportName-->
                            <testSuite>ErrorCodes</testSuite>
                            <junitReport>false</junitReport>
                            <printReport>true</printReport>
                            <exportAll>true</exportAll>
                            <soapuiProperties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>soapui.home</name>
                                    <value>C:\Users\pulipge\ReadyAPI-1.3.0\bin</value>
                                </property>
                            </soapuiProperties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Allure maven plugin should be in reporting section only. In regular dependencies you need

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-junit-adaptor</artifactId>
    <version>${allure.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

instead. Also for advanced Allure features (like attachments and test steps) you need to configure *aspectj* and *java agent* in *maven surefire plugin*.

Please check the details at https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-junit-example.git.

Comment: However I'm not sure if JUnit adapter is suitable in that case. SoapUI is in fact a GUI tool. Does it generate JUnit tests?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks miheys, Vania. I see now Allure report getting created!! Pls see attmt.
But it says 0 Testsuites, 0 Testcases[image]
What could be the reason. I ran the case against 1 test suite. Can you pls check. Also I tried allure-junit-adaptor, it errored out that it cannot find files to download. So I ram wihout it. Here is my POM below.

Here is the POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.smartbear.soapuiMavenTutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>SoapUI-Maven-Tutorial</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SoapUI-Maven-Tutorial</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


        <parent> 
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId> 
         <artifactId>allure-examples-parent</artifactId> 
         <version>1.0</version> 
     </parent> 

     <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
         <aspectj.version>1.8.6</aspectj.version>
        <allure.version>1.4.14</allure.version>


    </properties>



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId> 
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
              <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version> 
        </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.14</version>
    </dependency>


        <!--Added this junit adaptor-->
            <!--dependency>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-junit-adaptor</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency-->


        <!--added jdbc below in build element-->
    </dependencies>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
                        <version>10.2.0</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                        <!--systemPath>C:\maven\ojdbc6.jar</systemPath-->
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <groupId>com.smartbear</groupId>
                <artifactId>ready-api-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>


                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectFile>C:\Gee-SoapUI-Projects-Backup\25Aug2015-POSBkup\May04-2015-Point of Sale.xml</projectFile>
                            <outputFolder>C:\26-Aug-1suiteResults</outputFolder>
                            <reportFormat>xUNIT</reportFormat>
                            <reportName>TestCase Report</reportName>
                            <!--reportName>TestSuite Report</reportName-->
                            <testSuite>ErrorCodes</testSuite>
                            <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                            <printReport>true</printReport>
                            <exportAll>true</exportAll>
                            <soapuiProperties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>soapui.home</name>
                                    <value>C:\Users\pulipge\ReadyAPI-1.3.0\bin</value>
                                </property>
                            </soapuiProperties>

                                <properties> 
48                         <property> 
49                             <name>listener</name> 
50                             <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener</value> 
51                         </property> 
52                     </properties> 


                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

 <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>

             <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
      </plugin>         

        </plugins>
    </reporting>    

</project>
```